# Set StatusBarStyle in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uistatusbar

I have set the `ViewController-Based Status Bar Appearance` to `true` in `info.plist` file.

in my ViewController, I set

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent;
}
```

But my status bar is still black. Any ideas?

Comment: I need to have different style in different View Controllers @pedrouan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue to use view controller based status bar appearance, instead of setting the application's `statusBarStyle`, override the `preferredStatusBarStyle()` method in each view controller for which you'd like to specify a status bar style.

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```